# How to get only particular control get updated layout in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have layout with itemscontrol inside. But How to detect `LayoutUpdated` only for the itemscontrol. When I set itemscontrol layoutudpate event it calls repeatly. I don't know how this `LayoutUpdated` can be called..

```
itemscontrol.LayoutUpdate+= ItemControlHal7_LayoutUpdated;
```

and the method:

```
private void ItemControlHal7_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MessageBox.ShowMessage("Updated");

    }
```

It calls many times I only want to detect this when the data in itemscontrol changes.

Comment: what are you trying to do with this? I don't think this is the proper solution for whatever problem you're trying to resolve.

Comment: if you're trying to change the UI based on changes in the collection you need to use `Style`s and possibly `DataTrigger`s. Read up on those topics and don't try to use WinForms way in WPF, you will face a lot of difficulties, try [MvvM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680271/Simplest-MVVM-Ever).